# return all json objects containing specific keyword using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm looking to return all json objects that contains a specific keyword.

```
DATA = [
    {
        "candidateName" : "Jack",
        "candidateEmail" : "Jack@gmail.com",
        "candidateSkills" : ["machine learning", "Artificial Intelligence"]
    },
    {
        "candidateName" : "John",
        "candidateEmail" : "John@gmail.com",
        "candidateSkills" : ["python", "machine learning"]
    },
    {
        "candidateName" : "Smith",
        "candidateEmail" : "Smith@gmail.com",
        "candidateSkills" : ["python"]
    }
]
```

If i want to return all those objects containing "python" in above json file using python, how to do that?

What i already tried is=>

```
**def result():
              with open(DATA.json) as jsondata:
              data = json.loads(jsondata)
              return (list(filter(lambda x:x["candidateName"].find("python"), data)))**
```

And output i am getting is null.

Comment: Why are you looking at the `candidateName` key instead of `candidateSkills`?

Answer (score 1):

Ummm... Your looking in the wrong place. Look at `candidateSkills`.

```
newData = [obj for obj in DATA if "python" in obj['candidateSkills']]
```

output

```
[{'candidateName': 'John', 'candidateEmail': 'John@gmail.com', 'candidateSkills': ['python', 'machine learning']}, 
 {'candidateName': 'Smith', 'candidateEmail': 'Smith@gmail.com', 'candidateSkills': ['python']}]
```

Comment: Thanks @BuddyBob it's working, i want to know if i need to return all those objects with multiple keywords, like i want "python", "machine learning" both together. How do i do this?

Comment: if ["python","machine learning"] in obj['candidateSkills']]

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

def result():
    with open("DATA.json") as jsondata:
        data = json.load(jsondata)
    return([candidate for candidate in data if "python" in candidate["candidateSkills"]])

result()
```

This is how I would do it.

It will return a list of all the dictionaries where python is in the candidateSkills.

Comment: Thanks! It's working, i want to know if i want to search for two values like "python" and "Artificial Intelligence" together. In that case how should i proceed to get all different objects containing above keywords.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```
import json

with open("sample.json") as jsondata:
    data = json.loads(jsondata.read())


skill_list = ["machine learning"]
def check_all_skills(words, skills):
    for word in words:
        if word in skills:
            return True
    return False


result = [element for element in data["DATA"] if check_all_skills(skill_list, element["candidateSkills"])]
print("Result: ", result)
```

Output:

```
Result: 
[{
    'candidateName': 'Jack',
    'candidateEmail': 'Jack@gmail.com',
    'candidateSkills': ['machine learning', 'Artificial Intelligence']
}, {
    'candidateName': 'John',
    'candidateEmail': 'John@gmail.com',
    'candidateSkills': ['python', 'machine learning']
}]
```

Comment: Thanks! It is working, might be my previous comment on above two replies not well explained. But what i am actually looking for is i want all those objects from json which do contains these specific keywords. like if in your post skill_list = ["python", "Artificial Intelligence"] - both from different objects, so i want to return both these objects in my output.

Comment: edited code to match any skill from a list.